# Embedding multiple tableviews into detailview

Tags: ios5, xcode4.4

I am very new to iOS and GUI programming in general, but I seem to be getting the hang of the very basics of it, but I'm truly stumped and could use some hand holding if possible. I am working on a master-detail iPad application. The navigation controller is working properly, but I'm having some issues with the detail view controller. It is split up into 3 separate sections vertically. The first section consists of standard controls (labels, image view, etc) and the other two sections consist of table views.

I cannot, for the life of me, figure out how to get the table views to populate any data in the tables. From what I have gathered, I need to setup a datasource and delegate for each of the table views, but I can't seem to figure out where/how to do that.

Can anyone point me in the right direction please? Thanks.